How to restore an multi levels deep related model in Laravel
I'm developing an application in Laravel.
The problem is that when I try to restore an model with all it's related models, some of them do not restore. I guess it's because they are multi level deep related.
Here is the code for restoring items:
$contract = Contract::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$contract->restore();

$contract->load(['acceptanceActs' => function ($query) {
   $query->withTrashed()->with('invoice');
}]);

foreach ($contract->acceptanceActs as $act) {
    $act->restore();

    if ($act->invoice) {
         $act->invoice->restore();
    }
}

return response()->json();

So the problem is that related invoice to acceptance act does not restore, but contract and acceptance acts do.
Here are my models:
Contract:
/**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function client(): BelongsTo 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function acceptanceActs(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AcceptanceAct::class);
    }

AcceptanceAct:
/**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function client(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function invoice(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function contract(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contract::class);
    }

Invoice:
/**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function client(): BelongsTo 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function items(): HasMany 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceItem::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function acceptanceAct(): BelongsTo 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AcceptanceAct::class);
    }

All of them use soft deletes.

A would edit and simplify your code like this and it should work properly. Problem is that you are not using withTrashed scope on the query that is loading invoice from the database.
$contract = Contract::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$contract->restore();

$contract->acceptanceActs()
    ->withTrashed()
    ->get()
    ->each(function (AcceptanceAct $acceptanceAct) {
        $acceptanceAct->restore();

        $acceptanceAct->invoice()->withTrashed()->first()?->restore();
    });

return response()->json();

